# R: sort barplot colors

Tags: r, plot

**I have a matrix of data which generate barplot like:**

[image]

**I want my barblot to be like:**

[image]

Where as I note in the comments, the blue segments should always be on the bottom. This is my R code:

```
file<-read.csv(file="file.csv", sep="\t", header=T)
    m<-table(file)
    m
         path
    mir              cp eip gip mt os
      aga-bantam      0   0   0  4  0
      aga-let-7       0   0   0  2  5
      aga-miR-1       0   0   0  3  0
      aga-miR-10      0  11   9  2  0
      aga-miR-100     4   0   0  0  0
      aga-miR-1000    2   2   0 15  0
      aga-miR-11      5   0   0  0  0
      aga-miR-1174    4   0   0 10  0
      aga-miR-1175    0   0   0  6  0
      aga-miR-12      0   3   0  0  0
      aga-miR-124     0   0   0  8  0
      aga-miR-133     0   5  19  0  0
      aga-miR-137     0   0   2  0  0
      aga-miR-13b     0   0   9  0  0
      aga-miR-184     0   0   0  9  2
      aga-miR-1889    0   0  11  2  0
      aga-miR-1890    0   0   5 11  0
      aga-miR-1891    0   0   0  3  0
      aga-miR-190     0   4   0 13  0
      aga-miR-2       0   0  10  0  0
      aga-miR-210     0   0   0  4  0
      aga-miR-219     0   3   5  0  0
      aga-miR-263     0   2   0  0  7
      aga-miR-263b    0   3   0 16  4
      aga-miR-275     0   4   0  7  2
      aga-miR-276-3p  0   0   4 20  0
      aga-miR-276-5p  2   0   0  4  0
      aga-miR-277     0   0   0 20  0
      aga-miR-278     0   0   0  3  0
      aga-miR-279     0   5   0  0  0
      aga-miR-281     6   5   4  5  0
      aga-miR-282     4   2  15  4  0
      aga-miR-283     0   0   7  1  0
      aga-miR-305     0   3   5 10  0
      aga-miR-307     0   0   0  4  0
      aga-miR-308     0   0   0  0  2
      aga-miR-309     0   0   0  9  0
      aga-miR-315     0   0   0 13  0
      aga-miR-317     0   0   0  4  2
      aga-miR-34      0   3   0  3  0
      aga-miR-375     0   0   0  2  2
      aga-miR-7       0   0   0 10  0
      aga-miR-79      0   0   0  5  0
      aga-miR-8       0   0   3  2  0
      aga-miR-87      5   2   4  0  0
      aga-miR-927     0   0  11  0  0
      aga-miR-929     0   0   0  3  0
      aga-miR-92a     0   0  10  4  0
      aga-miR-92b     0   2   9  0  0
      aga-miR-957     0   0   0  8  0
      aga-miR-965     5   0   0 10  0
      aga-miR-970     0   0   7  5  0
      aga-miR-981     0   4   0  4  0
      aga-miR-989     0   0   0  8  0
      aga-miR-993     0   2   0  3  0
      aga-miR-996     0   0   3  2  0
      aga-miR-9a      0   0   0  3  0
      aga-miR-9b      5   0   0  2  0
      aga-miR-9c      0   0   0  5  0
      aga-miR-iab-4   5   0   0  0  0

    barplot (t(m),col=rainbow(5),las=2)
```

Comment: What is the problem? The colors are always in the correct order, according to your example. Perhaps you mean that you wish your data were identical to what was used for your example?

Comment: thanks for your reply, for example I need all blue values to be in the bottom, as you can see its appeared in bottom sometimes and sometimes in the middle and sometimes in the top.

Comment: Your blue values only appear at the bottom when there is no green, yellow, or red below them. Just like the green in your second example, where two of them are at the bottom because there is no red below them.

Comment: @Mushal What he means is that you ought to provide quite a bit more information in your question, especially sample code and sample data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for tips on how to create a reproducible example.  Unless you edit this question, it is likely to be closed as too vague and not answerable in its current form.

Comment: Without a reproducible answer, we are left guessing to what went wrong here. It looks like the order of the colors are always correct, but that not always all the colors are plotted. Could it be that for a lot of entries you have NA values?

Please paste some R code which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2):

With your added code, I can reproduce your graph. Note that some of the bars won't contain a blue segment, since in your data, some values in that column are in fact zero. But we can rearrange the segment orders by rearranging the columns of your data and the associated colors:

```
#You data was a table, but it was easier for me to copy+paste
# it and then read it as a data.frame
m <- read.table("~/Desktop/stackoverflowExamples/so.txt",header = TRUE,sep = "")
#Move the first column over to be the rownames
rownames(m) <- m[,1]
m <- m[,-1]

#Note that I just rearranged each piece so that the blue
# segments will be first; this includes the color and 
# legend text ordering
barplot(t(m[,c(4,1:3,5)]),col=rainbow(5)[c(4,1:3,5)],
        las=2,cex.names = 0.5,
        legend.text = colnames(m)[c(4,1:3,5)])
```

which produces something like this:

[image]

so that when that category is not zero, the blue segment will be at the bottom.